# Parameter relations of a linear equational system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to comprehend a calculation given in a paper.
http://www.math.utah.edu/~bresslof/publications/15-6.pdf

The task is the following:

We want to find a relation between $\omega$ and $\tau$.
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:matrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -\omega & \alpha_I cos(\omega \tau) & \alpha_I sin(\omega \tau)
\\ \omega & 1 & -\alpha_I sin(\omega \tau) & \alpha_I cos(\omega \tau)
\\ -\alpha_E cos(\omega \tau) & -\alpha_E sin(\omega \tau) & 1 & -\omega
\\ \alpha_E sin(\omega \tau) & -\alpha_E cos(\omega \tau) & \omega & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
U_E
\\ V_E
\\ U_I
\\ V_I
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0
\\ 0
\\ 0
\\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

In the paper, the authors argue that the determinant of the matrix must vanish if a nontrivial solution exists. But this gives us merely one condition.
So, they assume that $V_E = 0$ and $U_I = 0$. By doing so, we get four conditions, which indeed allow us to find a relation between $\omega$ and $\tau$.

But how can one argue that this is a legitimate assumption?

Comment: Where is the paper, which letters are variables and which are constants?

Comment: May help that 1 and -w are first order taylor expansions of cos and sin around 0.